# OpenX: Banner link target=_self is not working

Tags: openx

It seems OpenX (2.8.7) doesn't take into account the attribute "target".
I tried using "_self" and "_top" but when clicking on the banner it always opens a new (_blank) window.

I found nothing interesting on their forum.
Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What kind of tag/banner/zone are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Setting target to '_top' should open in current window/tab.